# How can I solve TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'property' and 'property'

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

I tried to do calculation by retrieving values by its index and column name for any pair of two rows in a for loop in Python but the TypeError popped up. IRdelta_WS_agg is a named tuple list and ws1.WS and ws2.WS are not read properly. Does anyone have idea to solve this? Many thanks!

```
for bucket in buckets:
    for ws1 in IRdelta_WS_agg:
        for ws2 in IRdelta_WS_agg:
            correl = get_ir_delta_phi_rho(ws1.RiskType, ws1.Curve, ws1.Tenor,
                                        ws2.RiskType,ws2.Curve, ws2.Tenor)
            variance = ws1.WS * ws2.WS * correl
            K += variance
```

```
    variance = ws1.WS * ws2.WS * correl
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'property' and 'property'
```

Comment: How are get_ir_delta_phi_rh and WS defined?

Comment: `WS` is of some data type that does not support the `*` operator